# Veracode flagging api action with optional parameters for not having input validation

Tags: c#, api, routes, swagger, veracode

I'm using dot.net WebApi2 and I'm getting Veracode Flaw from code scan:

'*The Controller's Action is missing a Route Attribute that will perform input validation on Action parameters using a Route Constraint....
Remediation: Make sure to use RouteAttribute objects with a Route Constraint on each Action*'

The action referred to is:

```
[Route]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int? offset = null, int? rows = null)
{
    ...
}
```

Since I only have optional parameters, they are not specified in the Route attribute. If I do by changing thr route annotation to:

[Route("{offset:int?}/{rows:int?}"]

the route would show in the swagger api help page like this:

GET /api/v1/foo/{offset}/{rows}

instead of (what we want to show):

GET /api/v1/foo

the help page would also have those parameters marked as required, even though they should not be.

Is there a way I can please Veracode and not spoil my swagger doc's?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: nope. ended up mitigating it